# How to get all files from a directory in Azure BLOB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

We are storing the application logs in `Azure BLOB` storage. We are currently downloading the files using the complete URI to the file. Every time when the settings of `Azure BLOB` is changed, the file name also gets changed. So we are getting error as file not exists.

Suggest a way to get the files using file extension from a directory without having file name in UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ListBlobs()` method to retrieve all blobs for a specific container and then you could use the static .NET `Path.GetExtension()` method to retrieve the file extension so you can filter them. Example:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("yourCS");

var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(container);

var list = container.ListBlobs();
var blobs = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>()
    .Where(b => Path.GetExtension(b.Name).Equals("yourextension"))
```

Comment: Worth noting here is that the filtering will happen on client side. It will list all blobs in a blob container first and then apply filtering. Depending on the number of blobs in a container, it may take some time.

Comment: This seems outdated. I can not find any `ListBlobs` only a `ListBlobsSegmentedAsync` and that thing does not have a `OfType` method

Comment: Yeah this did not age well, it seems.

Comment: Use a CloudBlobDirectory: CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(directoryPath); var blobs = directory.ListBlobs();

Comment: CloudBlobDirectory.ListBlobs() doesn't exist anymore, either.

Comment: @ChrisG.Williams Switch to latest Microsoft.Azure.Storage (v11 SDK) package to get ListBlobs()